# How can I get clickable elements from a table using Puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, puppeteer, webautomation

I'm trying to scrape a website and there is a table with clickable elements and text. I managed to use this to grab the innerText of the table elements:

```
const result = await page.$$eval('tableselector tr', rows => {
    return Array.from(rows, row => {
      const columns = row.querySelectorAll('td');
      return Array.from(columns, column => column.innerText);
    });
});
```

I've tried just returning `columns` and using `result[row][column].getProperty('innerText').jsonValue()` to try and grab the innerText but it doesn't work. Could someone explain where I'm going wrong?

EDIT:
Here is an HTML Segment that represents the structure of the table I am trying to scrape.

```
<table id = "table_id">
<body>
    <!-- input button is the clickable element I want to grab -->
    <tr class = "GridRowStyle">
        <td>input button</td><td>text2</td><td>text3</td><td>text4</td><td>text5</td><td>text6</td><td>text7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class = "GridAlternatingStyle">
        <td>input button</td><td>text2</td><td>text3</td><td>text4</td><td>text5</td><td>text6</td><td>text7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class = "GridRowStyle">
        <td>input button</td><td>text2</td><td>text3</td><td>text4</td><td>text5</td><td>text6</td><td>text7</td>
    </tr>
</body>
```

Comment: This code looks fine. If `result` doesn't contain the 2d result array, maybe you could show the page you're scraping or a [mcve] of the relevant HTML.

Comment: It does return the result array, but it's just if I try to return just ```columns```, I only get an array of empty fields or undefined.

Comment: That's right, because these are HTML elements. I might have misunderstood -- you want to actually click on some of these cells or are you trying to get their contents? If you want to get the first column of `<td>` elements, `await page.$$("table td:nth-child(1)")` should work, then you can click each one if that's what you're trying to do. That said, the HTML you show is invalid. You may have meant `tbody` rather than `body`? It's better to show the actual page since it can have arbitrary JS that this might be oversimplifying, and explain what you're actually trying to achieve here. Thanks.

Comment: I can't show the page, but I'll give your suggestion a shot. I'm trying to get the contents of the cells after the first one and the clickable elements of the first column. So, I guess both.

Comment: OK, I understand, but you can "always" (usually) create a simple, representative mock-up of the site that's reproducible. Otherwise, we're sort of hand-waving and it's not possible to really answer the question for you without a lot of guesswork.